# expressjs not rendering computed html string on browser

Tags: node.js, express

I am reading a HTML file in express and modifying some of its content. I want the modified HTML content to be rendered in browser, however it renders a blank page with source as the modified HTML content. Any idea why? My code is:

```
 app.get('/', (req, res) => {
          let v = fs.readFileSync('./index_original.html', 'utf8');
          data = v.replace(/\$OG_TITLE/g, 'Hello World');
          data  = data.replace(/\$OG_DESCRIPTION/g, 'Hi There');
          data  = data.replace(/\$OG_IMAGE/g, 'https://via.placeholder.com/150');
          res.type('.html');
          res.send( data);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to check browser console if there is a error there, and the nodejs console. And, do the variables get replaced correctly?

Comment: no error anywhere , that is why I am at a loss :( @srknzl

Comment: do the variables get replaced correctly?

Comment: yes absolutely correctly.

Comment: I think there is not any problem in your app.get code, you should look for the error somewhere else. Maybe share more?

Comment: that's precisely what I am trying to figure out , where to look for

Comment: I think you should share more if you can

Comment: what is it that you want me to share

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196479/discussion-between-srknzl-and-satya).

Answer (score -1):

I think you got a minor mistake there. The correct syntax for res.type() is without the dot. 
Check out: [here](https://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res.type)

This should work out:

```
 app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      let v = fs.readFileSync('./index_original.html', 'utf8');
      let data = v.replace(/\$OG_TITLE/g, 'Hello World');
      data  = data.replace(/\$OG_DESCRIPTION/g, 'Hi There');
      data  = data.replace(/\$OG_IMAGE/g, 'https://via.placeholder.com/150');
      res.type('html'); 
      res.send(data);
});
```

Comment: both .html and html are listed there . Tried with both, none worked

Comment: @Satya Have you tried out printing out the steps one after another? May one of the steps breaks it.

Comment: I see the html source of the page and it has the correct HTML , not sure why it is not being rendered correctly

Comment: "The correct syntax for res.type() is without the dot." this is not correct. In the link you give it is shown that both are fine.